# Assembly code to print a new line string

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I have an assembly code to print (display) a string. My problem is I'm not able to how print two string into different line!

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 100H

.DATA
MSG1 DB 'Fun $'
MSG2 DB 'Day!$'
.CODE 
MAIN PROC
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX 

LEA DX,MSG1
MOV AH,9
LEA DX,MSG2
MOV AH,9

INT 21H 

MOV AH,4Ch 
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```

The output should be like:

```
Fun 
Day!
```

But in Result:

```
Day!
```

Help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the `INT 21H` call for the first part, that's why only the second is printed. As for the two lines, just append a CR LF to your string. You can also print the whole thing at once, such as:

```
.MODEL SMALL 
.STACK 100H

.DATA
MSG DB 'Fun', 10, 13, 'Day!$'
.CODE 
MAIN PROC
MOV AX, @data
MOV DS, AX 

LEA DX,MSG
MOV AH,9
INT 21H

MOV AH,4Ch 
INT 21H

MAIN ENDP
END MAIN
```